# Typeset matrix from Array in Typst

Tags: arrays, typst

I'm trying to do and show a Matrix Multiplication in Typst. I implemented the basic O(n³) algorithm for matmul and it's working. My return value is an array of arrays. Now I want to show the content of the matrix as a `$ mat() $`.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77596174/typst-unwrap-array-as-horizontal-colums/77777945) and something very similar to what I want is being done, but with a table.

```
table(
    columns: C.len(),
    rows: C.first().len(),
    ..for row in C {
      for cell in row {
        (str(cell),)
      }
    }
)
```

However, that `..for` destructuring seems not to be possible on `$ mat() $`.

So how do I pass a matrix (array of arrays) to a `$ mat() $` function to be typeset?

Full source code: https://typst.app/project/rGXaEQsB1LzGgXw9KO39Dv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so: `$ #math.mat(..C) $`. You need to use the spreading operator but it only works in code mode which we reenter with `#` here.